# get rowIndex a button in a tablerow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to get the rowIndex of a button in a table? Nothing works for me:

```
let tr = $('<tr class="tableRow"></tr>');
let td = $('<td class="noWrap"></td>');

let btn = $('<button type="button" class="btn btnEdit"></button>');
td.html(btn);

tr.html(td);
$('#table1 > tbody:last-child').append(tr);

$('.btnEditMenge').on('click', ()=>{
    $(function(){
        let rowindex = $(this).clostest('tr').rowIndex     // undefined
        let c = $(this).closest('.tableRow');              // Array[0]
        let b = $(this).parent();                          // Array[0]
    });
});
```

The comments in the onClick Listener is, when I click the button.

Comment: Can you explain what `clostest` is/does?

Comment: You have wrapped your logic incorrectly inside jQuery ready method (inside the click-event) remove that wrapper.

Comment: There's several issues in your code, such as the use of `this` in an arrow function, the document.ready handler in the click event handler, jQuery objects having no `rowIndex` property, no mention of where `.btnEditMenge` is  in the HTML. In fact, to answer this effectively we need to see the related HTML

Comment: It is closest() in my code...it is a jquery function to find siblings/parent elements in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

A little refactoring in your code:

```
let tr = $('<tr class="tableRow"></tr>');
let td = $('<td class="noWrap"></td>');
let btn = $('<button type="button" class="btn btnEdit"></button>');

btn.appendTo(td);
td.appendTo(tr);
tr.appendTo($('#table1 > tbody:last-child'));

// Or: 
// btn.appendTo(td.appendTo(tr.appendTo($('#table1 > tbody:last-child'))));

$('.btnEditMenge').on('click', function() {
    let $btn = $(this);
    let rowindex = $btn.closest('tr').index();
    let $tableRow = $btn.closest('.tableRow');
    let $parent = $btn.parent(); 
});
```

1. Use [`appendTo()`](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)(or [`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/), [`before()`](https://api.jquery.com/before/), and so on...) instead of [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) to append DOM elements;
2. Use [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to get any element's index;
3. Don't use *arrow functions* for events, [`this` could not be what you're expecting](https://blog.logrocket.com/anomalies-in-javascript-arrow-functions/);
4. [`$(function() { })`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) is not for that purpose, it is used to bind an event in the `document.ready` event. It should not be used inside another event;
5. Try to give functional names to variables. Avoid names like `b` or `c`.

Answer (score 0):

It was this line:

```
$('.btnEditMenge').on('click', ()=>{
```

It works, when I change it to

```
$('.btnEditMenge').on('click', function(){
```

I always thought it is the same...